Set Spark configuration when running python in dbt for BigQuery
Making some progress on a proof of concept for a python dbt model in GCP (BigQuery).  Built a dataproc cluster for Spark and able to execute the model, but I'm getting an error in the model that requires a configuration change for Spark.  Specifically, I need to set the following:
"spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInRead": "CORRECTED"
"spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInWrite": "CORRECTED"        "spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInRead": "CORRECTED"         "spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite": "CORRECTED"
I'm uncertain where/how to set these spark configuration options.  Is it in the profiles.yml file or can I do it programatically in the python model itself...or somewhere else?
Tried setting the following in the profiles.yml file:
analytics_profile:
outputs:
dev:
server_side_parameters:
"spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInRead": "CORRECTED"
"spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInWrite": "CORRECTED"
"spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInRead": "CORRECTED"
"spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite": "CORRECTED"

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm getting the following error when running my python dbt model:
You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: writing dates before 1582-10-15 or timestamps before 1900-01-01T00:00:00Z into Parquet files can be dangerous, as the files may be read by Spark 2.x or legacy versions of Hive later, which uses a legacy hybrid calendar that is different from Spark 3.0+'s Proleptic Gregorian calendar. See more details in SPARK-31404
In researching fixes, I need to set the spark settings referenced above, but I don't know where/how to set those spark settings

In researching fixes, I need to set the spark settings referenced above, but I don't know where/how to set those spark settings

It should have been obvious, but I didn't connect the dots that the spark config was part of the session object that gets passed into the model function.  This fixed the error I was getting:
session.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite", "CORRECTED")
session.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInWrite", "CORRECTED")
session.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInRead", "CORRECTED")
session.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite", "CORRECTED")

